# Improving (subjective) speed of Ajax request by Lazy Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm working on a website which displays content stored in a MySQL database using Ajax requests. Because the TTFB and general content download takes too long I am looking for a better solution.

Currently there is only one Ajax request being executed which loads all items from the database.

**I am thinking of two options to improve:**

1. Programming a Lazy load function, which sends an Ajax request whenever new items come into viewport.
2. Splitting the Ajax request in more requests (for example requesting only 10 items at a time). This way the user wouldn't need to wait so long for the whole chunk to load.

But I am not sure on how to implement it wisely.

As I am not an expert when it comes to Ajax I may be totally wrong with these ideas. Also I would be glad to hear some alternative suggestions.

I'm also currently working on additional performance improvements such as minimizing content and images but I think some other more fundamental changes are necessary to make the user experience more enjoyable.

Maybe the actual website helps for a better understanding:

http://zeitlos-artd.de/products.html

Comment: #1 implies you can also do #2, then it just a matter of optimization for the UX. look into _pagination_.

Comment: Look into something like this: http://www.infotuts.com/ajax-infinite-scroll-using-jquery-php-mysql/. It does both #1 and #2 of your suggestion.